# C++ Run-Time Library is set to /MT, but api-ms-win*.dll's are still missing

Tags: c++, multithreading, winapi

I'm using Visual Studio 2013 (v120_xp), and I'm programming using static libraries. "Run-Time Library" is set to /MT (multithreading), so I don't need extrenal .dll's. Today I added a function to display [Windows 8 toast notifications from desktop app.](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsdesktop/sending-toast-notifications-71e230a2) Everything works fine, but when I'm testing the program on a Virtual Machine with Windows XP or Vista it shows that "api-ms-win-core-winrt-string-l1-1-0.dll" and "api-ms-win-core-winrt-l1-1-0.dll" were not found. When I paste the mentioned *.dlls to the same folder as the .exe - everything runs fine. My question is: What should I do, to link those .dlls as static? I hate to use additional .dll's and I want my program to be very portable (limited just to 1 .exe file). Sorry if my question is not clear enough, but I hope it's understandable. I treat programming as a hobby, so there are still many things I have to learn.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are calling functions that are not available on versions earlier than Windows 8. Copying DLLs is certainly wrong. You absolutely cannot legally distribute Windows DLLs and in any case you cannot expect to use DLLs designed for one version on a different version.

You will need to use dynamic runtime linking to these DLLs and only call these functions on Windows versions that support this functionality.

Link dynamically either by using `/delayload` or by making explicit calls to `LoadLibrary` and `GetProcAddress`.

Comment: Thank you so much! It works great! Of course I'm using some bools like "IsWinEightOrLater()" to prevent calling those functions on the older Windows versions. About those DLLs - I've pasted version "6.2.9200.16384" and it worked fine on XP/Vista - but you're right, the "6.3.xxx" version from Windows 8.1 was crashing instantly. So I totally agree that it wasn't a good choice. Thanks again for help!

Comment: Don't ever copy system DLLs around. Even if it seems to work it's always wrong.

Comment: Using OS version checking (which BTW, Microsoft has its own [`IsWindows8Point1OrGreater()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dn424962.aspx) helper function) to decide whether to call a given function is not the best choice (and with the breakage of `GetVersionEx()` in Win8.1, is even more error-prone moving forward). The *BEST* option is to not rely on OS version numbers at all. Use `GetProcAddress()` to test whether the desired function actually exists before then calling it. That will always give a proper result, and allow for installable stubs in older OS versions.

Comment: Remy makes a good point. If you use GetProcAddress, let it guide you. If you use delayload then version checks are needed. So long as you app is correctly manifested though, functions like `IsWindows8Point1OrGreater()` are fine.

Comment: Thank you for additional tips! I was using some Major/Minor version check (updated to the microsoft's versionhelper now). I'll be testing the 'GetProcAddress()', the only problem is I don't know what DLLs what functions use, but I'll look in it more deeply.

Comment: The msdn docs should have the information. But version checking is not necessarily wrong.